# traefik.go: command traefik error: failed to eval New: undefined: xxx

Tags: go, traefik, traefik-plugins, yaegi

I am trying to build a Traefik plugin and test it in local mode based on https://github.com/traefik/plugindemo#local-mode

Right now this plugin does nothing and just returns "Hello".

Here is my file structure:

[image]

In the `traefik/plugins-local/src/github.com/Hongbo-Miao/traefik-plugin-disable-graphql-introspection` folder, I have:

**.traefik.yml**

```yaml
entryPoints:
  graphql-server-entrypoint:
    address: :9000
api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true
providers:
  file:
    filename: dynamic_conf.yaml
log:
  level: DEBUG
experimental:
  localPlugins:
    traefik-plugin-disable-graphql-introspection:
      modulename: github.com/Hongbo-Miao/traefik-plugin-disable-graphql-introspection
```

**go.mod**

```golang
module github.com/Hongbo-Miao/traefik-plugin-disable-graphql-introspection

go 1.17
```

**main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
)

type Config struct{}

func CreateConfig() *Config {
    return &Config{}
}

type DisableGraphQLIntrospection struct {
    next http.Handler
    name string
}

func New(ctx context.Context, next http.Handler, config *Config, name string) (http.Handler, error) {
    return &DisableGraphQLIntrospection{
        next: next,
        name: name,
    }, nil
}

func (a *DisableGraphQLIntrospection) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    rw.Write([]byte("hello"))
}
```

In the root folder, I have

**traefik.yaml**

```yaml
entryPoints:
  graphql-server-entrypoint:
    address: :9000
api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true
providers:
  file:
    filename: dynamic_conf.yaml
log:
  level: DEBUG
experimental:
  localPlugins:
    traefik-plugin-disable-graphql-introspection:
      modulename: github.com/Hongbo-Miao/traefik-plugin-disable-graphql-introspection
```

**dynamic_conf.yaml**

```yaml
http:
  routers:
    graphql-server-entrypoint:
      service: graphql-server-service
      entrypoints:
        - graphql-server-entrypoint
      rule: Host(`localhost`)
      middlewares:
        - my-traefik-plugin-disable-graphql-introspection
  services:
    graphql-server-service:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://localhost:5000/
  middlewares:
    my-traefik-plugin-disable-graphql-introspection:
      plugin:
        traefik-plugin-disable-graphql-introspection:
          headers:
            Foo: Bar
```

I have a GraphQL sever running at http://localhost:5000

I want it go through Taefik and expose by http://localhost:9000

However, when I run

```
traefik --configfile=traefik.yaml
```

in the root folder, I got error

> traefik.go:79: command traefik error: failed to eval New: 1:28: undefined: traefik_plugin_disable_graphql_introspection 119

Traefik plugins are executed on the fly by [Yaegi](https://github.com/traefik/yaegi), an embedded Go interpreter.

The error seems threw by Yaegi, however, I have no clue how to debug.

Any guide would be appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an answer from Tom Moulard and thanks! https://github.com/traefik/plugindemo/issues/15#issuecomment-1123741949

> Your error means that Yaegi cannot find the `New` function of the `traefik_plugin_disable_graphql_introspection` package. Therefore, you can tell that Yaegi found your plugin, loaded it, but could not find the package. To fix this, you need to change the line `package main` in your plugin's code, to `package traefik_plugin_disable_graphql_introspection`.

After changing `package main` to `package traefik_plugin_disable_graphql_introspection` in the **main.go** file, it works now!